# How to adjust saturation value in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

How to adjust saturation value in android?

kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an RGB colour, you can convert it to HSV using [suitable Color methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). Then adjust the saturation value as appropriate, and convert it back.

Comment: I have tried using below code but it is not working,              public static Bitmap applySaturation(Bitmap o, float deg)
  {        
        Bitmap srca = o;
        Bitmap bitmap = srca.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        for(int x = 0;x < bitmap.getWidth();x++)
            for(int y = 0;y < bitmap.getHeight();y++){
                    int newPixel = saturationChange(bitmap.getPixel(x,y),deg);
                    bitmap.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);
            }

        return bitmap;
  }

Comment: private static int saturationChange(int startpixel,float deg){
        float[] hsv = new float[3];       //array to store HSV values
        Color.colorToHSV(startpixel,hsv); //get original HSV values of pixel
        hsv[1]=hsv[1]+deg;                //add the shift to the HUE of HSV array
        hsv[1]=hsv[1]%1;                //confines hue to values:[0,360]
        return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(startpixel),hsv);
     }